# Complex Analysis, the Sum of Residues is Imaginary?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, branch-cuts

I'm trying to solve this problem using complex analysis:

$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2-2x+3}\, dx$

I'm using a contour that avoids the branch cut along the +x axis of the complex plane, looking like a block capital C.

Ive shown that the two circular portions of the contour drop to zero as you shrink the inner circular contour and grow the outer one.

The remaining two straight portions of the contour sum to be twice that of the intergral I'm trying to solve. The problem is the the poles of the above formula give residues of:

$\frac{1}{2} i \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}} $

and

$\frac{-1}{2} i \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}} $

Here's my problem: $2 \pi i \sum \text{Residues}$ is an completely imaginary number, giving my integral no real value.

Am I using the wrong contour, or am I just missing something really simple and the value of my integral is just zero?

Thanks for any help

Comment: i would guess that you don't use the correct phases for the calculation. keep in mind that with your choice of logarithm, $i=e^{i \pi/2}$ AND $-i=e^{i 3\pi/2}$.

Comment: Sorry could you elaborate a little? I really struggle with this stuff. 

I'm using a phase of zero on one straight line portion, and 2pi on the other portion. All this shows is that together they are 2 times the value of the integral I'm trying to find.

Comment: How exactly did you get those poles?

Comment: Apologies, these are the residues, editing now

Comment: $\ 1 - i\sqrt{2}$ and $\ 1 + i\sqrt{2}$ are the poles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suppose that you cut along $\Bbb R^+$ and that you picked $\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+}\sqrt{1+ \varepsilon i} = +1$,
so that $\sqrt x$ always has a positive imaginary part.

Then your contour includes two poles, at $x = 1 \pm \sqrt{2}i$ and where $\sqrt x$ have positive imaginary parts in both cases. You most likely picked one with positive imaginary part and another one with negative imaginary part instead.

The residue at $x$ is $\sqrt{x}/(x-\bar x)$, and summing them gives $(\sqrt x - \sqrt {\bar x}) /(x- \bar x) $.

If $\sqrt x = a+ib$ with $b>0$ then $\sqrt{\bar x} = -a+ib$, so $\sqrt x - \sqrt {\bar x} = 2a$, so the sum of the residues is $\pm ai/\sqrt{2}$, which is purely imaginary (the sign depends on which $x$ you choose when computing the square root).

After multiplying by $2i\pi$ you get $\pm a\pi\sqrt 2$, a real number.

And really everything would be more simple and apparent if you made a change of variable $y = \sqrt x$

Comment: Thankyou so much! 

It never crossed my mind to make a substitution either, it would have definitely made things clearer your right.